# A tricky limit (indeterminate form)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

While tutoring I came upon this limit. I know that this limit is obviously 1, but how would I show this formally

$$\lim_{\eta\rightarrow\infty}[(2\eta + 5)^x-(2\eta)^x + 1]$$ where $x\in (0,1)$

I've tried logarithms etc.

Comment: You should give us more details as to what you have tried so that we can find out where you are having difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
\lim_{\eta \to \infty}(2 \eta + 5)^x - (2 \eta)^x = 
\lim_{\eta \to \infty}
5\eta^{x-1}\frac{(2 + 5/\eta)^x - 2^x}{5/\eta}
$$

---

Alternative approach: make the substitution $t = 1/\eta$ to rewrite this as
$$
\lim_{t \to 0^+} (2/t + 5)^x - (2 /t)^x = 
\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{(2 + 5t)^x - 2^x}{t^x}
$$
Now, apply L'Hopital.

Comment: Not sure if this is ideal for tutoring though; there must be a L'Hopital's trick along these lines

Answer (score 0):

Another way than the one suggested by Omnomnomnom is the following. Forget about the $+1$ for a moment and consider
$$\begin{aligned}
(2\eta + 5)^x - (2\eta )^x & = (2\eta)^x\left(1+\frac{5}{2\eta}\right)^x-(2\eta)^x\\
& = (2\eta)^x\left(\left(1+\frac{5}{2\eta}\right)^x-1\right).
\end{aligned}$$
Then you can use that
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(2\eta)^x\left(\left(1+\frac{5}{2\eta}\right)^x-1\right)& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{5}{2\eta}\right)^x-1}{\frac{1}{(2\eta)^x}}
\end{aligned}
$$
And then you can infer Hospitals rule.

Comment: I just figured that in this way one obtains a limit which still needs some effort to be computed, so maybe Hospitals rule is not the right thing to do since things don't really get better. So my answer is just a hint how to make it amenable to Hospitals rule but not really an answer - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

By the MVT
$$0<(2\eta+5)^x-(2\eta)^x=5\> x(2\eta +\tau)^{x-1}$$
for some $\tau\in\>]0,5[\>$. Since the RHS converges to $0$ when $\eta\to\infty$ the limit in question is $1$.